# Two dataframes after merging in r are showing <0 rows> (or 0 length row names)

Tags: r, csv, merge

I'm learning R from Code School and currently doing problems in chapter 6. Now whatever I learn there, I practice it offline in my desktop.

Now, the problem I am facing seems relatively very simple but I cannot find any easy answer.

In this chapter, we are introduced with two datasets. 
Both have the same four **ports**.

First dataset, which is named as `Targets` have three columns (`Port`, `Population`, and `Worth`)

```
Port    Population  Worth
Cartagena    35000  10000
Porto Bello  49000  15000
Havana      140000  50000
Panama City 105000  35000
```

and second dataset, which is named as `Infantry` have two columns (`Port`, and `Infantry`).

```
Port        Infantry
Porto Bello      700
Cartagena        500
Panama City     1500
Havana          2000
```

Both dataset are saved in two separate csv files.
Now after loading them

```
Targets = read.csv(file.choose()) 
Infantry = read.csv(file.choose()
```

whenever I try to merge them by typing

```
merge(Targets,Infantry)
```

the result shows:

> ```
> [1] Port       Population Worth      Infantry  
> <0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)
> ```

Comment: Since there are no reproducible examples, what kind of help do you want to get?

Comment: There are no datasets, no codes, and the output is in a bad format. If I write a post like yours, just describe an issue I encountered, would you be willing to help me?

Comment: Please show us sample data here.  Make your question reproducible.  I sinned by answering, because I thought I had a silver bullet fix, which I didn't.

Comment: Sorry, I am new here. This is my first question. So, I didn't know the ways. Next time, I'd keep your advice in mind. Thank you :)

Comment: You need to indent your input 4 times to show it inside code blocks. Show us example rows and columns the way they actually look, in table format. Same thing with your merge code. Have a look at how other top-voted R questions are asked.

Comment: @St.Lazarus ; can you edit your question with the results of `dput(head(Targets))`, and `dput(head(Infantry))` please.

Comment: Check for any leading/lagging spaces in the 'Port' column i.e. `Targets$Port <- trimws(Targets$Port); Infantry$Port <- trimws(Infantry$Port)` and then do the `merge`  Based on what you showed, it should merge correctly

Comment: user20650 thanks for your kind reply.

Comment: akrun thanks a lot. Now it worked. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

When creating some dummy data from you example, the merge function works fine.

```
  Targets <- data.frame(
  Port=c("Cartagena", "Porto Bello"),
  Population=c(35000, 49000),
  Worth=c(10000, 15000))

Infantry <- data.frame(
  Port=c("Porto Bello", "Cartagena"), 
  Infantry=c(700, 500))

merge(Targets,Infantry)
```

Can you check if the `read.csv` function uploads the files correctly? You may need to change the argument `sep` in the read.csv function or `by.x` and `by.y` of the merge function?

Comment: Check for any leading/lagging spaces in the 'Port' column i.e. Targets$Port <- trimws(Targets$Port); Infantry$Port <- trimws(Infantry$Port) and then do the merge Based on what you showed, it should merge correctly – akrun 20 mins ago

Comment: I guess the problem was for leading/ lagging space. Now it worked. Thanks anyway :)

Comment: SeGa, unrelated, but best not to use `data.frame(cbind(..))`, as it coerces all columns to character, then factor (see `str(Targets)`), including the columns that should be numeric. Jusy use `data.frame(...)`