# How to perform subset comparison in between two CSV whereas one is subset of another?

Tags: r, csv, comparison, subset, matching

I have two CSV's, imported as dataframe, given below:

`dd1 <- read.csv("C:\\Users\\sharmb5\\Desktop\\Truth Dataset\\Buckets.csv",stringsAsFactors = FALSE, header = TRUE, sep = ",", blank.lines.skip = TRUE)`

`dd <- read.csv("C:\\Users\\sharmb5\\Desktop\\test dataset\\Buckets.csv", header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE, sep = ",", blank.lines.skip = TRUE)`

`dd1` (with 6 rows and 6 columns) is a subset of `dd` (with 6 rows and 6 columns) dataframe (entries may be shuffled). I want to do that subset matching in between `dd` and `dd1`.

**Attempts**

1. `library(plyr)
   merge(dd, dd1)`
2. `intersect(dd,dd1)`
3. `inner_join(dd,dd1)`
4. `fintersect(dd,dd1)`
5. `merge.data.frame(dd,dd1)`

I tried above all function along with respective packages, but give the same output

> [1] Bucket    Account   X..Objects   Chargeable.Capacity   Region 
>    Bucket.Creation.Date
>   <0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)

and if read the CSV's with `fread` method, a response is the same.

`dd <- fread("C:\\Users\\sharmb5\\Desktop\\test dataset\\Buckets.csv",stringsAsFactors = FALSE,blank.lines.skip = TRUE)`

`dd1 <- fread("C:\\Users\\sharmb5\\Desktop\\Truth Dataset\\subset.csv",stringsAsFactors = FALSE,blank.lines.skip = TRUE)`.

I can't understand where is the problem, because the same functions work well when I gave data manually(i.e. creating some random data frame).

**Updated**

dput(head(dd)) is:

```
`structure(list(Bucket = c("ireland-bucket", "singapore-test-bucket", 
"virginia", "sydney-testbucket", "test-testing-purpose", 
"aws123"), Account = c("Kishore", "Kishore", "Kishore", "Kishore", 
"Kishore", "Kishore"), X..Objects = c(2L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 57L
), Chargeable.Capacity = c(5.22e-05, 5.02e-06, 0.000104157, 5.23e-05, 
4.54e-05, 0.008055141), Region = c("eu-1", "ap-1", 
"us-2", "ap-1", "us-2", "us-1"), Bucket.Creation.Date = c("2017-08-28T08:12:21.000Z", 
"2017-08-28T08:15:22.000Z", "2017-08-29T05:09:14.000Z", "2017-08-29T05:14:03.000Z", 
"2019-03-12T13:57:23.000Z", "2017-08-22T10:13:36.000Z")), row.names = c(NA, 
6L), class = "data.frame")`
```

and dput(head(dd1)) is

```
`structure(list(Bucket = c("ireland-bucket", "singapore-test-bucket", 
"virginia", "sydney-testbucket", "test-testing-purpose", 
"aws123"), Account = c("Kishore", "Kishore", "Kishore", "Kishore", 
"Kishore", "Kishore"), X..Objects = c(2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 57L
), Chargeable.Capacity = c(5.22444024682045e-05, 5.01330941915512e-06, 
0.000104157254099846, 5.22788614034653e-05, 4.53982502222061e-05, 
0.00805514119565487), Region = c("eu-west-1", "ap-southeast-1", 
"us-east-1", "ap-southeast-2", "us-east-2", "us-east-1"), Bucket.Creation.Date = c("2017-08-28T08:12:21.000Z", 
"2017-08-28T08:14:22.000Z", "2017-08-29T05:09:14.000Z", "2017-08-29T05:14:01.000Z", 
"2019-03-12T13:57:23.000Z", "2017-08-22T10:13:36.000Z")), row.names = c(NA, 
6L), class = "data.frame")`
```

Help me to rectify this issue. Thank you for suggestions.

Comment: May be related (leading white space?): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50435712/two-dataframes-after-merging-in-r-are-showing-0-rows-or-0-length-row-names

Comment: @cgrafe  I tried the same that you referred, but the output is same (didn't work for me) and still not able to figure out the problem.

Comment: I want to do one more thing with this, completely match of `dd1` in `dd` data frame (either full data frame `dd` or subset of `dd`). It should return true if entire `dd1` found in `dd` (either subset or full) and false, if doesn't match.

Comment: Do you need `merge(dd, dd1, all = TRUE)` ?

Comment: @RonakShah yes it works, thanks. Please refer this [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56541863/10738353) , the actual requirement is given in that question.