# how find or match one data frame as a subset(full) into another data frame in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, subset, matching

I have two data frames df1 and df2 given below.
`df1` is

```
  c1       c2   c3  c4
   B  2.34000  1.00  I
   A 14.43000  2.10  J
   D  3.45515  1.00  K
   B  2.50000  2.09   
   A  2.44000  1.10  K
   K  5.00000  1.09  L
```

`df2` is:

```
  c1    c2   c3
   B  2.34  1.00
   A 14.43  2.10
   D  3.43  1.00
   B  2.50  2.09
   E  5.00  1.09
   A  2.44  1.10
```

the requirement here is like this: there is matching(or comparison) between these two data frames. if `df2` completely found (**that means the content of `df2` matched with any subset of `df1` irrespective of the order**) in `df1`(either exactly matched with `df2` or subset of `df1` matched with `df2`) then output is `true`. If not matched then return `false`.

**I tried following methods:**

```
1. left_join(df2,df1)
2. merge(df2,df1)
3. inner_join(df2,df1)
4. dd1[dd1$c1 %in% dd$c1,]
```

all the above methods give that data which is common in between both but not give results as per requirements.

Please suggest me some solution for the same.

Comment: completely found means identical rows are found ? or found exactly in the same order bundled together ? can you edit and be more precise ? Please also mention if `df1` and/or `df2` can contain duplicate rows

Comment: you might want `nrow(dplyr::intersect(df1[1:3], df2[1:3])) == nrow(df2)`

Comment: @Moody_Mudskipper `intersect` will not work when the number of columns are not equal, but I want all entries from `df2`  matched with `df1` irrespective to dimensions of the `df1`.

Comment: In my comment both arguments have the same number of columns, you can use names instead of numeric indices if needed.

Comment: @Moody_Mudskipper it will perfectly work with square type data frames but I want to give a generic code for rectangular data frames.

Comment: sorry I don't understand what you mean by square data.frame, I understand square as being as wide as long, and it's not the case in my example.

Comment: @Moody_Mudskipper square data frame means number of rows and number of column are equal. rectangular data frame means number of rows and columns are not equal.

Comment: Yes that's what I understood and I believe it's irrelevant here, and irrelevant altogether with concept of data frames. The dfs I used were 3x6

Comment: @Moody_Mudskipper its okay but you suggested that `nrow(dplyr::intersect(df1[1:3], df2[1:3])) == nrow(df2)` it only give common data of both doesn't says that `df2` is present in to `df1` (either `df2` as asubset of `df1` or full`df1`).

Comment: In one case, there is a possibility that `nrow` of `df1` and `df2` are the same but data may not be the same. In your piece of code if rows are the same it will be `TRUE` but actually, it is not desirable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `match` and `interaction` like:

```
df1 <- read.table(text="c1       c2   c3  c4
   B  2.34000  1.00  I
   A 14.43000  2.10  J
   D  3.45515  1.00  K
   B  2.50000  2.09  NA
   A  2.44000  1.10  K
   K  5.00000  1.09  L", header=T)

df2 <- read.table(text="c1    c2   c3
   B  2.34  1.00
   A 14.43  2.10
   D  3.43  1.00
   B  2.50  2.09
   E  5.00  1.09
   A  2.44  1.10", header=T)

!any(is.na(match(interaction(df2), interaction(df1[names(df2)]))))
#[1] FALSE

#And packed in a function
"%completelyFoundIn%" <- function(x, y) {!any(is.na(match(interaction(x), interaction(y[names(x)]))))}

df2 %completelyFoundIn% df1
#[1] FALSE

df2[c(1,2,4,6),] %completelyFoundIn% df1
#[1] TRUE

df2[-5,c(1,3)] %completelyFoundIn% df1
#[1] TRUE
```

Comment: if I remove second the last row in `df2`, then `df2` is surely present in `df1`(irrespective to order rows or data) but your code will return `FALSE` but it should return `TRUE` because `df2` exists in `df1`.

Comment: @Bhavneetsharma in `df2` you have `D  3.43  1.00` which is not in `df1`. In df2 you have something similar `D  3.45515  1.00` but `3.43` is not equal to `3.45515`.